# How to capitalize letter (using \uppercase) that has been assigned to \let (or to \def)?

Tags: expansion, capitalization

I don't seem to be able to capitalize a letter that has been assigned to `\let`.

```
\let\zTest=t
\uppercase{\zTest} % still small
```

ADDENDUM: I've tried `\def\zTest{t}` just now and it didn't work either (but `\uppercase{t}` works).

Comment: With a recent version of LaTeX you could do `\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\expanded{<stuff>}}`, that would work with `<stuff>` being letters and macros defined using `\newcommand` or `\def`, but not for `\let`.

Comment: `\uppercase` and `\lowercase` only act on explicit character tokens. Implicit character tokens and macros expanding to character tokens are not touched. An character token produced with `\let` doesn't have a `\uccode` (or `\lccode`) for `\uppercase` to do its thing. Try ``\showthe\uccode`t`` and then ``\showthe\uccode`\zTest`` (the latter raises an error).

Comment: @bp2017 Did you see the 'tl action' approach I linked to in an earlier question: you can pick up spaces in advance, and process them without `\let`, if you are prepared to normalise the charcode of `{`/`}`.

Comment: It might be useful to post a question with your actual use case: at the moment, this feels like an X-Y question. I'm not sure what actual use case you have.

Comment: `\uppsercase` does no expansion: when you use `\def`, the macro token is not affected as it's not a char

Comment: @bp2017 *"prevent spaces from being gobbled"* --  You can have TeX "look" whether there are some spaces. In this context the routines `\UD@CheckWhetherNull`, `\UD@CheckWhetherBrace`, `\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace` in my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510311/118714) to the question "How do I pad a string argument to a macro to a set length string" might be of interest. ;-)

Comment: the answer to the real problem behind this question is almost certainly "don't use `\let`":  If you use `\def` it is easy to arrange uppercasing to work as you just need to expand macros first, but making it work with implicit characters is _much_ harder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\uppercase` and `\lowercase`

- do only apply to **explicit character tokens**.
- **do not trigger expansion** after finding

  - either the left brace `{` of the `⟨balanced text⟩` that is to be uppercased/lowercased.
  - or the single not-brace-nested unexpandable non-`⟨filler⟩`-token that is to be uppercased/lowercased. (`⟨filler⟩` denotes a sequence of `\relax` and/or explicit/implicit spaces.)

When using `\csname..\endcsname` instead of using the control-word-token directly, you can probably do somehing like this:

```
\let\zTest=t
\let\ZTEST=T
\let\ztest=t
\def\Ztest{t}

% \zTest and \ZTEST and \ztest are implicit character tokens.
% Let`s use uppercased/lowercased \csname..\endcsname for selecting 
% which implicit character token to use:

\csname zTest\endcsname

\uppercase{\csname zTest\endcsname}%

\lowercase{\csname zTest\endcsname}%

% \Ztest is a macro, expanding to explicit character token "t".
% You can use \expandafter for triggering "toplevel-expansion"
% while \uppercase/\lowercase still searches the "{" that
% marks the begin of the balanced text:

\Ztest

\uppercase\expandafter{\Ztest}%

\lowercase\expandafter{\Ztest}%

% With more recent TeX-engines, where \expanded is available,
% you can do:
%   \lowercase\expandafter{\expanded{\Ztest}}%
% "toplevel-expansion" of \expanded<general text> will deliver
% "total expansion" of the content of the <general text>'s 
% <balanced text> 

\bye
```

Answer (score 5):

The following is a macro that is able to uppercase a let token if it was let to a letter (e.g., with `\let\foo=t` assuming standard category codes). It does so by first checking whether the magic tokens `the letter` are the start of the meaning of the passed in token, and then grabs the letter following it and uppercases that, if the meaning doesn't seem to be a letter then the input is output. The test is only applied to the first token of the input, but it is not checked whether the input is only a single token (so `\uppercaselettoken{t more stuff}` would see that `t` is a letter but passes `more stuff` to `\uppercase`, too. So this is only a proof-of-concept not a stable implementation.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\let\foo=t

\makeatletter
\def\uppercaselettoken@ifletter#1%
  {%
    \def\uppercaselettoken@ifletter##1#1##2\end
      {%
        \if\relax\detokenize{##2}\relax
          \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \else
          \if\relax\detokenize{##1}\relax
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo
          \else
            \expandafter\@secondoftwo
          \fi
          {\expandafter\@firstoftwo}
          {\expandafter\@secondoftwo}%
        \fi
      }%
    \def\uppercaselettoken@letter#1##1\end{\uppercase{##1}}%
  }
\expandafter\uppercaselettoken@ifletter\expandafter{\detokenize{the letter }}
\long\edef\uppercaselettoken@#1#2%
  {%
    \noexpand\uppercaselettoken@ifletter#1\detokenize{the letter }\noexpand\end
      {%
        \noexpand\uppercaselettoken@letter#1\noexpand\end
      }%
      {#2}% not a letter, no uppercasing
  }

\newcommand\uppercaselettoken[1]
  {%
    \expandafter\uppercaselettoken@\expandafter{\meaning#1}{#1}%
  }
\makeatother

\usepackage{unravel}

\begin{document}
\uppercaselettoken{\foo}
\uppercaselettoken{t}% works too
\end{document}
```

Comment: Might add this to `\tl_upper_case:n`

Comment: @bp2017 well, we have to teach TeX something which was originally not meant to be done, so yes, this tends to be complicated.

Comment: @JosephWright not sure whether it should be part of `\tl_upper_case:n`, but one could define a variant (something like `\tl_upper_case_e:n`) which does this. It's your choice :)

Comment: I sometimes use implicit characters and/or `\char` in situations where uppercasing/lowercasing of initials and shortcuts of names and the like is to be prevented.. ;->

Answer (score 3):

[image]

While it is possible to implement something that interrogates the meaning of unexpandable tokens, recognises implicit characters defined by `\let` and look up their upper case form, there are very few reasons to get into that situation, using `\def` (or `\renewcommand`) is the documented LaTeX interface and is essentially trivial to make work as you just have to expand the macros before uppercasing, and it works out of the box using LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\let\zza=a
\let\zzb=b
\let\zzc=c

1 \MakeUppercase{\zza\zzb\zzc}


\renewcommand\zza{a}
\renewcommand\zzb{b}
\renewcommand\zzc{c}

2 \MakeUppercase{\zza\zzb\zzc}


\end{document}
```